# How to build AJAX data from url params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, coffeescript

Goal: if no param present, do query (this is working), but if param is present do a different query.

It seemed pretty straight forward: pass the param (or not), in the controller check if the param existed, if so do new query, if not, do old query.  Pass the data onto AJAX and coffeescript.

By looking at my log it appears that rails uses the controller twice - once on initial page load and a second time when it has the AJAX data.  Since it's doing this twice, I seem to be loosing my param value when it goes through a second time.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

**relevant part of my controller**

```
@pId = params[:id]
puts params.inspect
if @pId.present?
  puts "-- Id present --"
  @points = Point
    .select('points.genus, points.species, points.cultivar, points.common_name, types.type_name')
    .where(id: @pId)
    .eager_load(:type)
else
  puts "** Id not present **"
  @points = Point
    .select('points.genus, points.species, points.cultivar, points.common_name, types.type_name')
    .where("types.type_name like 'Tree-%' or types.type_name like 'Shrub-%' or types.type_name like 'Perennial' or types.type_name like 'Fern' or types.type_name like 'Vine-%'")
    .order(:id)
    .eager_load(:type)
end
feature_collection = Point.to_feature_collection @points
@geojson = RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(feature_collection)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @geojson }
  format.html
end
```

**relevant part of my coffeescript**

```
$.ajax
  dataType: 'text'
  url: 'map.json'
  send: () ->
    $('#loading').show()
  complete: () ->
    $('#loading').hide()
  success: (data) ->
    L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(data),
      pointToLayer: plantToMarker)
```

**Update**
Now that I'm not cold medication and my head is no longer fuzzy, I'm going to try again.  I suspect I'm either missing something conceptually is the page load cycle, or I don't understand how AJAX works (also likely, because this is my first time working with it).

If I use the url `localhost:3000/map` my page displays, loads a JS library for mapping, and plants_controller.rb does a query with results in a couple hundred plant points getting drawn on the map using my coffeescript.

That's working just fine.  I want everything to remain the same when I use the url `localhost:3000/map?id=3` except rather than the query returning many points it should only return #3.

I always thought this would be a linear process that fired once - sort of like page loads, controller is processed and data generated, js library loaded, ajax sent, js finished drawing the map.  If I understand what I see in my logs, we seem to be going through the controller twice  - the first time, if the id param is present, it processed the code.  However, on the second pass through it doesn't find the id, and ends up loading all the plant points.  I can't for the life of me understand why the controller is getting access twice, and why the second time it is failing to recognize the id.

@joel I tried to implement your suggestion and I'm either not doing it correctly, or it isn't helping

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @pId.present?
    format.json { render json: @geojson, data: @pId}
  else
    format.json { render json: @geojson }
  end
  format.html
end
```

Comment: you don't seem to be sending any params in your ajax call , add a 'data' attribute with the param you want to the call

Comment: Are you sending the ajax call to the same action? If so, you can get a current url with all parameters and use it in your ajax request. Replace `url: 'map.json'` with `url: window.location.pathname`. And add `dataType: 'json'` if required. If the url is different and you need only parameters, you can easily extract them from the current url.

Comment: @chumakoff I'm not sure what you mean by "the same action", but perhaps I'm not explaining myself well.  Everything works as expected when I'm not looking for a param.  The query generates several hundred results and passes it to the AJAX call and my coffeescript.  I'm trying to add a second query which would generate only one record (based on the id that was passed to the page), and then send that via AJAX to my coffeescript.